# MongoDB sort & limit problems

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My problem is that I want to return the docs of the last five created entries in the database. I know that something like:

```
return Events.find({}, {sort: {createdOn: -1, limit: 5}});
```

should work but it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`sort`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sortspecifiers)** specifier should be a separate property to the limit option:

```
return Events.find({}, {sort: {createdOn: -1}, limit: 5});
```